# In Hammerspoon how do I get the currently focused application name on startup?

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I can get the application name after the user switches focus with the following code:

```
function applicationWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
  if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated) then
    print(appName)
  end
end

local appWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationWatcher)
```

But I'd like this `appName` right after hammerspoon initializes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the `hs.application.frontmostApplication()` function: http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.html#frontmostApplication :)